# python error - "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm really new at Python so I apologize in advance if this is a really dumb question. Pretty much, I'm writing a longest common subsequence algorithm with dynamic programming.
Whenever I try to run it, I get the `IndexError: list index out of range`, and I don't know why because the array I'm adding values to never changes in size. Code snippet for clarity:

```
def LCS(sequence1, sequence2):
    n = len(sequence1)
    m = len(sequence2)
    D = [[0 for num in range(0,n)]for number in range(0, m)]
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, m):
            if(sequence1[i] == sequence2[j]):
                D[i][j] = D[i-1][j-1] + 1
            else:
                D[i][j] = max(D[i-1][j], D[i][j-1])
    print D[n][m]
```

Comment: I think you meant `print D[n-1][m-1]`, or just `D[-1][-1]`

Comment: Please make sure your answer shows a minimal research effort. Have you googled the error to see what it means? How have you tried to debug your code so far?

Comment: Also, Python usually prints out the error line. It really tries to be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I researched it and tried to debug my code...and that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two problems:

1. In the definition of `D`, you should swap `n` and `m`

   ```
   D = [[0 for num in range(0, m)] for number in range(0, n)]
   ```
2. You have to print (or better: return) the last element of the matrix

   ```
   return D[n-1][m-1] # or just D[-1][-1]
   ```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH that was the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with total rows and columns of the matrix(D). Size should be `(m+1)*(n+1)` and then loop over the matrix. Otherwise you need to return D[m-1][n-1].

```
def LCS(sequence1, sequence2):
    n = len(sequence1)
    m = len(sequence2)
    D = [[0 for num in range(0,n+1)]for number in range(0, m+1)]
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, m+1):
            if(sequence1[i-1] == sequence2[j-1]):
                D[i][j] = D[i-1][j-1] + 1
            else:
                D[i][j] = max(D[i-1][j], D[i][j-1])

    print D[n][m]

LCS('abcdef' , 'defjkl')
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question what's wrong with OP's code, right?